# Could I use a heatsink to interconnect transistors mounting base?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, heatsink

I'm designing a CMOS H-bridge single sided board. To keep it small as possible, I would like to not connect the transistor's drain by trace. In spite off, as they are connected to the mounting base and I will be using heatsink, I would like to know if this connection is enough. This doesn't sound a good design to me, but since it's a low current application (2A, with 4A peak), I think there will be no much problem (actually, the heatsinks are not even mandatory, since them are almost at room temperature).

The question is, how bad is this practice? Should I really avoid it at any costs or are there specific cases that I'm allowed to do this?

Comment: Much of the black anodizing that plates many heat-sinks is non-conductive. To make electrical contact, sometimes "star-washers" are used to bite through the plating.

Comment: It's a heatsink entirely made of aluminum. There's not any material covering it, just aluminum.

Comment: I bet at least aluminum-oxide is covering it, which is a pretty good isolator.

Comment: Sure. But it has a large area of contact. Is this really concerning?

Comment: Do you realize that you've left out the single most important detail here, which is the package of your transistors? Also the exact transistor type may matter. Some manufacturers recommend not using the tab to carry current, at least for certain IC power amps... That's why you've got only vague answers from low-rep users.

Comment: For example, the OPA452 datasheet says: "The tabs of the DDPAK-7 and TO220 packages are electrically
connected to the negative supply (V–), however, these
connections should not be used to carry current. For best
thermal performance, the tab should be soldered directly to
the circuit board copper area (see Heat Sinking section)." On the other hand, the datasheet for TC4421A explicitly allows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the heatsink as a common drain for all transistors if your heatsink is not covered with paint but:
- It is mandatory to use a screws with washer in order to make a good contact.
If you use the circuit outside or in a humid environment probably after few months will appear some oxid on your heatsink and the contact resistance will be bigger (can rise until your aplication will stop working).

Another disadvantage of using the heat plate as only way of conductive part is that your MOS will have a greater response delay. If in datasheet it is written 5ns-tr, you will have more than 10ns because the layout is designed for a fast response when voltage is applied to the pin and the drain is connected to pin not to heatplate.

Comment: Good answer assuming he's using something that can be screwed like TO-220. Also one can use Alnox (or similar products) to greatly reduce the oxidation speed at the screw.

Answer (score 0):

The heatsink should be use with some thermal paste or a material that conducts heat, if you want to connect the drain to heatsink you cannot add thermal paste.Only with some screw could make the contact.In this case should work because the heatsink is a low resistance material.

Comment: Is there any specific reason? I think it does not make much sense, since even with the thermal grease there will be enough metal/metal contact. Beyond this, there is a lot of thermal greases with low resistance properties, like the silver ones.

Comment: The silver one should work for good contact.

Comment: Exactly. The thermal grease just fill the gaps between the heatsink and transistor. So, I suppose it will lower the contact resistance between the mounting base and heatsink in spite off rise it. I can only see the resistance getting higher if I add so much grease.

Comment: Doesn't aluminum oxidize? What material heat sink are you using and how will you ensure its surface is conducting as good as the transistor's case and your silver thermal paste?

Comment: It's an aluminum heatsink.

Comment: Even if it is oxidize will be a low resistance material if when you apply the silver paste you clean the contact surface.